# RecursiveDirectoryIterator Removing Dot folders

Tags: php

Currently I have the code below what would be the best way for me to be able to set the flags in the code below so I can use `::SKIP_DOTS`?

**Code:**

```
  $folder = 'images/banner_img';?>

    <?php foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder)) as $filename): ?>
      <?php $fileTypes = array("db"); 
            $fileType  = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            if(!in_array(strtolower($fileType), $fileTypes)):?>


         <img src="<?php echo $filename; ?>" alt="" title="" data-thumb="<?php echo $filename;?>" />

       <?php endif;?>

    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS` [as an option (in the second parameter)](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystemiterator.construct.php) to `new RecursiveDirectoryIterator()` should be sufficient to work with your current code.

With PHP 5.3+, you may alternatively declare the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` as its own variable then call a method on that variable:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
$iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
// Still need to pass $iterator to a RecursiveIteratorIterator...
```

`setFlags()` is a method [inherited from the `FilesystemIterator` base class](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystemiterator.setflags.php).

But since you are already using the template formatting `foreach: / endforeach;` style, it makes sense to just do it in the nested declaration rather than using additional variables.

```
<!-- Instead, stick with your current iterator declaration and -->
<!-- add RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS as the 2nd param to its constructor -->
<?php foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS)) as $filename): ?>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
```

Comment: If you want `RecursiveIteratorIterator` also return the Dir children, you should use `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST`:

Answer (score 0):

The flag `::SKIP_DOTS` was raising an error `GET / - Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'SKIP_DOTS'` on some machines.

**Alternative** bellow to skip hidden folders, hidden files and the navigation dots `.` `..`

```
$cwd = './targetdir';
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($cwd), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );

// Skip hidden directories and hidden files
foreach ( $iterator as $path ) {
  if(!$path->isFile()) continue;
  $dirname = explode("/",$path->__toString());
  $dirname = substr($dirname[count($dirname)-2], 0, 1);
  if($dirname === ".") continue;
  if(substr($path->getFilename(), 0, 1) === ".") continue;

  if ($path->isDir()) {
      print($path->__toString() . "<br>");
   } else {
      print($path->__toString() . "<br>");
  }
}
```